# Get Partial View to load Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, controller

I have a controller post (Index POST) that returns a partial view (Modal). This partial view is to load data from a model that is returned from its respective Get ActionResult method. It ignores this method.  Is there a way to make it load data from the controller?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public ActionResult Index(string date)
    {
        string[] dateSplit = date.Split(new char[] { 'T' });

        DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateSplit[0]);
        TempData["date"] = objDate;

        return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Modal.cshtml");
    }
```

This is the partial View's Get Method, which doesn't load when the Index post returns the partial view.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Modal()
{
    var content = db.Calendars.ToList();
    if(TempData["date"] != null)
    {
        DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["date"]); 
        var contentDate = db.Calendars.Where(x => x.startDate == objDate).ToList();

        return PartialView(contentDate);
    }


    return PartialView(content);



}
```

Here is the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<webby.Models.Calendar>



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding:20.5% 15%;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Events on @ViewBag.Date</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                    @foreach(var item in Model)
                    { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.events)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.type)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.content)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }


                </table>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#myModal').modal();
</script>
```

After running the application and once the post returns the partial view, the partial view catches a null error.

Answer (score 0):

return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Modal.cshtml");

The above line is not going to call your Modal() action. It will simply try to return the View (cshtml). (And in this case you are not giving the view a model.)

You might pull off your goal by having the last line of Index (post):

```
return RedirectToAction("Modal");
```

(That said, I'm a bit unclear on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so a more detailed description might help get to a complete solution.)

Also, I don't know exactly what the ScriptMethod attribute is, but I'm pretty sure you don't want it decorating your post action.

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have modal actions.  When you call

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Modal.cshtml");
```

it is going to simply open the view with whatever you pass into it (which as written is absolutely nothing).

What you want to do is put the code:

```
var content = db.Calendars.ToList();
if(TempData["date"] != null)
{
    DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TempData["date"]); 
    content = db.Calendars.Where(x => x.startDate == objDate).ToList();
}
```

inside your HttpPost Index action and pass the model to the modal as such:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Modal.cshtml", content);
```